# Not able to edit text in Bash window

Tags: bash, azure

I am trying to deploy OpenEdx instance on MS Azure, for which I am following some instructions. I have created a Virtual Machine on Azure. It is an Ubuntu Linux VM. I have accessed the VM through a Git Bash window and I am stuck at below point in post installation process.

The instruction is like:

> Edit this line:
>
> ```
> edxapp:x:1003:1006::/edx/app/edxapp:/bin/false
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> edxapp:x:1003:1006::/edx/app/edxapp:/bin/bash
> ```

I have changed the line:

```
edxapp:x:1003:1006::/edx/app/edxapp:/bin/false
```

to:

```
edxapp:x:1003:1006::/edx/app/edxapp:/bin/bash.
```

But, it is not getting edited. Can any one guide me on this? How do I edit that line? Also,if possible please provide me with a script to complete the installation, if someone has done OpenEdx installation earlier.

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting edited" ? What editor are you using to edit the file with and how do you edit the editor ? Please update your question with the exact commands used.

Comment: I installed the OpenEdxwith some commands. Then as per instructions i set up the ports on azure for LMS and CMS. Then I wasasked to run following command:sudo vim /etc/passwd.      Then article told me to Edit as below.                                                       Edit edxapp:x:1003:1006::/edx/app/edxapp:/bin/false  to edxapp:x:1003:1006::/edx/app/edxapp:/bin/bash

Comment: @ChandrashekharPatil - what happened after you tried to save the file (e.g. using shift-Z-Z)?

Comment: @ChandrashekharPatil - did you `ssh` to the Ubuntu machine from your `git bash` window?

Comment: I just changed the text and pressed enter. I did not do shift z-z. Do I have to do?

Comment: Yes I ssh to my Ubuntu VM with Git bash.

Comment: This is to continue with my comment for .. SorenA. I changed the line edxapp:x:1003:1006::/edx/app/edxapp:/bin/false with this line:edxapp:x:1003:1006::/edx/app/edxapp:/bin/bash   and pressed enter. But as soon as I wrote some text there for editing, it is showing in white color as INSERT. 
but i don't think it is edited properly because whatever commands i run later on, it doesn't ex
ceuted. I don't know about bashand linux much. 
Please guide me properly.

Comment: As @Yaron wrote, you have to exit the editor properly to save your changes.

Comment: @ChandrashekharPatil - you should change the text, and press <ESC> follows by SHIFT-Z-Z, and let us know if the file was changed

Comment: Thanks brother. Is edited. But keep checking, as I am may need your help further...Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `vim` in order to edit a file, you should save the file before exiting.

One way to save the file before exiting is:

- Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> (in order to exit the *edit mode*)
- Press <kbd>Shift+Z+Z</kbd> In order to save the file and exit